# Blue Pelican Java Project 24 Reading Files

Tags: java, project, pelican

The project assignment is the following:

Write a class called FileNerd that will input the lines of text from a file named NerdData that
is stored in the temp_Larry folder (assuming your name is Larry). After the file input loop,
create a loop in which you printout only those lines that begin with the word “The”.

So this is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FileNerd
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Larry\\NerdData.txt"));
        int maxIndx = -1;
        String text[] = new String[100 ];
        while(sf.hasNext())
        {
            maxIndx++;
            text[maxIndx]=sf.nextLine();
        }
        sf.close();

        for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++)
        {
            String q = text[j];

            if( q.substring(3).equals("The"))
            {
                System.out.println(q);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because it compiles with no syntax error but nothing prints.

Comment: what is the contents of NerdData.txt. It seems that your file doesn't contain any "The"'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts on debugging:

- You can write additional `System.out.println(debug_msg)` statements throughout your code to understand what is going on.
- When you add these debugging lines you will usually find out how to solve your own problem.
- Additionally, you can use a debugger (most IDE's come with one). You can set break points to stop the program and walk through the code.

Looking at your code I don't see any obvious mistakes. I suggest adding this debug line for you to understand what is going on and debug it yourself.

```
for(int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++) {
     String q = text[j];
     // this will tell you what the contents of the line are
     System.out.println(q)

     if( q.substring(3).equals("The")) {
        System.out.println(q);
     }
}
```